# Laravel email validate issue and stop entire application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have faced an issue with my Laravel application. I am going to place an order then showing an error message like the attached image below. Please anyone can help me to solve this issue. I don't understand wherefrom come up this issue.

Also please give file location for easier.

Screenshot.[image]

```
    private function assertValidAddress($address)
{
    if (!$this->emailValidator->isValid($address, new RFCValidation())) {
        throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
            'Address in mailbox given ['.$address.'] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared a variable for email? You are sending an empty email, as I understand it. Try the following.

```
 \Mail::send('emails.template_name', $data, function ($message) use ( 
    $subject,$contact_email) 
        {
            $message->from(getcong('var_email'), getcong('var_name'));
            $message->to($contact_email)->subject($subject);
        });
```

Or share your email sending fuction to understanding complatly.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
```

/*
 * This file is part of SwiftMailer.
 * (c) 2004-2009 Chris Corbyn
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;

/**
 * A Mailbox Address MIME Header for something like From or Sender.
 *
 * @author Chris Corbyn
 */
class Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader extends Swift_Mime_Headers_AbstractHeader
{
    /**
     * The mailboxes used in this Header.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $mailboxes = array();

```
/**
 * The strict EmailValidator.
 *
 * @var EmailValidator
 */
private $emailValidator;

/**
 * Creates a new MailboxHeader with $name.
 *
 * @param string                   $name           of Header
 * @param Swift_Mime_HeaderEncoder $encoder
 * @param EmailValidator           $emailValidator
 */
public function __construct($name, Swift_Mime_HeaderEncoder $encoder, EmailValidator $emailValidator)
{
    $this->setFieldName($name);
    $this->setEncoder($encoder);
    $this->emailValidator = $emailValidator;
}

/**
 * Get the type of Header that this instance represents.
 *
 * @see TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_PARAMETERIZED, TYPE_MAILBOX
 * @see TYPE_DATE, TYPE_ID, TYPE_PATH
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getFieldType()
{
    return self::TYPE_MAILBOX;
}

/**
 * Set the model for the field body.
 *
 * This method takes a string, or an array of addresses.
 *
 * @param mixed $model
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 */
public function setFieldBodyModel($model)
{
    $this->setNameAddresses($model);
}

/**
 * Get the model for the field body.
 *
 * This method returns an associative array like {@link getNameAddresses()}
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFieldBodyModel()
{
    return $this->getNameAddresses();
}

/**
 * Set a list of mailboxes to be shown in this Header.
 *
 * The mailboxes can be a simple array of addresses, or an array of
 * key=>value pairs where (email => personalName).
 * Example:
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * //Sets two mailboxes in the Header, one with a personal name
 * $header->setNameAddresses(array(
 *  'chris@swiftmailer.org' => 'Chris Corbyn',
 *  'mark@swiftmailer.org' //No associated personal name
 *  ));
 * ?>
 * </code>
 *
 * @see __construct()
 * @see setAddresses()
 * @see setValue()
 *
 * @param string|string[] $mailboxes
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 */
public function setNameAddresses($mailboxes)
{
    $this->mailboxes = $this->normalizeMailboxes((array) $mailboxes);
    $this->setCachedValue(null); //Clear any cached value
}

/**
 * Get the full mailbox list of this Header as an array of valid RFC 2822 strings.
 *
 * Example:
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * $header = new Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader('From',
 *  array('chris@swiftmailer.org' => 'Chris Corbyn',
 *  'mark@swiftmailer.org' => 'Mark Corbyn')
 *  );
 * print_r($header->getNameAddressStrings());
 * // array (
 * // 0 => Chris Corbyn <chris@swiftmailer.org>,
 * // 1 => Mark Corbyn <mark@swiftmailer.org>
 * // )
 * ?>
 * </code>
 *
 * @see getNameAddresses()
 * @see toString()
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getNameAddressStrings()
{
    return $this->createNameAddressStrings($this->getNameAddresses());
}

/**
 * Get all mailboxes in this Header as key=>value pairs.
 *
 * The key is the address and the value is the name (or null if none set).
 * Example:
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * $header = new Swift_Mime_Headers_MailboxHeader('From',
 *  array('chris@swiftmailer.org' => 'Chris Corbyn',
 *  'mark@swiftmailer.org' => 'Mark Corbyn')
 *  );
 * print_r($header->getNameAddresses());
 * // array (
 * // chris@swiftmailer.org => Chris Corbyn,
 * // mark@swiftmailer.org => Mark Corbyn
 * // )
 * ?>
 * </code>
 *
 * @see getAddresses()
 * @see getNameAddressStrings()
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getNameAddresses()
{
    return $this->mailboxes;
}

/**
 * Makes this Header represent a list of plain email addresses with no names.
 *
 * Example:
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * //Sets three email addresses as the Header data
 * $header->setAddresses(
 *  array('one@domain.tld', 'two@domain.tld', 'three@domain.tld')
 *  );
 * ?>
 * </code>
 *
 * @see setNameAddresses()
 * @see setValue()
 *
 * @param string[] $addresses
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 */
public function setAddresses($addresses)
{
    $this->setNameAddresses(array_values((array) $addresses));
}

/**
 * Get all email addresses in this Header.
 *
 * @see getNameAddresses()
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
public function getAddresses()
{
    return array_keys($this->mailboxes);
}

/**
 * Remove one or more addresses from this Header.
 *
 * @param string|string[] $addresses
 */
public function removeAddresses($addresses)
{
    $this->setCachedValue(null);
    foreach ((array) $addresses as $address) {
        unset($this->mailboxes[$address]);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the string value of the body in this Header.
 *
 * This is not necessarily RFC 2822 compliant since folding white space will
 * not be added at this stage (see {@link toString()} for that).
 *
 * @see toString()
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFieldBody()
{
    // Compute the string value of the header only if needed
    if (null === $this->getCachedValue()) {
        $this->setCachedValue($this->createMailboxListString($this->mailboxes));
    }

    return $this->getCachedValue();
}

/**
 * Normalizes a user-input list of mailboxes into consistent key=>value pairs.
 *
 * @param string[] $mailboxes
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
protected function normalizeMailboxes(array $mailboxes)
{
    $actualMailboxes = array();

    foreach ($mailboxes as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($key)) {
            //key is email addr
            $address = $key;
            $name = $value;
        } else {
            $address = $value;
            $name = null;
        }
        $this->assertValidAddress($address);
        $actualMailboxes[$address] = $name;
    }

    return $actualMailboxes;
}

/**
 * Produces a compliant, formatted display-name based on the string given.
 *
 * @param string $displayName as displayed
 * @param bool   $shorten     the first line to make remove for header name
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function createDisplayNameString($displayName, $shorten = false)
{
    return $this->createPhrase($this, $displayName, $this->getCharset(), $this->getEncoder(), $shorten);
}

/**
 * Creates a string form of all the mailboxes in the passed array.
 *
 * @param string[] $mailboxes
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function createMailboxListString(array $mailboxes)
{
    return implode(', ', $this->createNameAddressStrings($mailboxes));
}

/**
 * Redefine the encoding requirements for mailboxes.
 *
 * All "specials" must be encoded as the full header value will not be quoted
 *
 * @see RFC 2822 3.2.1
 *
 * @param string $token
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function tokenNeedsEncoding($token)
{
    return preg_match('/[()<>\[\]:;@\,."]/', $token) || parent::tokenNeedsEncoding($token);
}

/**
 * Return an array of strings conforming the the name-addr spec of RFC 2822.
 *
 * @param string[] $mailboxes
 *
 * @return string[]
 */
private function createNameAddressStrings(array $mailboxes)
{
    $strings = array();

    foreach ($mailboxes as $email => $name) {
        $mailboxStr = $email;
        if (null !== $name) {
            $nameStr = $this->createDisplayNameString($name, empty($strings));
            $mailboxStr = $nameStr.' <'.$mailboxStr.'>';
        }
        $strings[] = $mailboxStr;
    }

    return $strings;
}

/**
 * Throws an Exception if the address passed does not comply with RFC 2822.
 *
 * @param string $address
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException If invalid.
 */
private function assertValidAddress($address)
{
    if (!$this->emailValidator->isValid($address, new RFCValidation())) {
        throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
            'Address in mailbox given ['.$address.'] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
        );
    }
}
```

}